# Diophantine with primes factorials

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, factorial

> Let $p\in \Bbb{P},\alpha\in \Bbb{N}$. Find all of the solutions of the
>   following equation: $$(p-1)!+1=p^{\alpha} \  \  \ ,p>6$$

**My attempt**

We can rewrite the equation as follows:

$$(p-1)!=p^{\alpha}-1$$
$$(p-1)!=(p-1)(1+p+p^2+...+p^{\alpha-1})$$
$$(p-2)!=1+p+p^2+...+p^{\alpha-1}$$

Then the best I could find out is that:

$$(p-2)!\equiv \alpha \pmod{p-1}$$

And in general if $ 2\leq k \leq p-1$:

$$k^{\alpha}=1   \pmod{p-k}$$

But then I don't know how to continue. Thank you for your time

Comment: I think taking $v_p$ may help, you get the $\alpha$ in

Comment: Hint: $1+p+\dots+p^{\alpha-1} \equiv ? \pmod{p-1}$. And $(p-2)! \equiv ? \pmod{p-1}$.

Comment: @MarcoVergamini what is $(p-2)! \mod p-1$ ?

Comment: Well, if $p$ is a prime greater than $6$, I bet $2$ and $(p-1)/2$ are two different numbers in $1, 2, \dots, p-2$, so...

Comment: @MarcoVergamini $0$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is in fact $0$.

Comment: @MarcoVergamini And then how can I continue knowing that $\alpha$ is multiple of $p-1$

Comment: How big can $\alpha$ be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93085/discussion-between-eureka-and-marco-vergamini).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe if $p>6$ then $(p-1)^2 | p^\alpha -1$ and hence $p-1 |\frac{p^{\alpha}-1}{p-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{\alpha-1} p^i\implies p-1 | \alpha \implies \alpha \geq p-1 $  but then $p^{\alpha}\ge p^{p-1}> (p-1)!+1$